# Hadamard / matrix product adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, numerical-linear-algebra

First of all I would like to thank everyone over here at mathoverflow for their amazing generosity and help (for both pros and newbies like myself).

I apologize if this question seems dumb; I'm a new masters student trying to learn this topic.

I'm performing a LASSO optimization:

$\min ||\mathbf{A}x - b||_2 \; \; \; \; \mathrm{subject\:to} \;\;\; ||x||_1 \leq \tau$

I'm solving this numerically using a spectral projected gradient solver ("SPGL1", specifically), which requires two matrices $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{A}^*$ (conjugate transpose).

Because of the large-size of the problem, I'm **not** representing $\mathbf{A}$ as an explicit matrix. Instead, I'm writing a function in my code that returns the values of the products $\mathbf{A}x$ and $\mathbf{A}^*r$.

$x$ is the vectorization of an original data matrix $\mathbf{X}$ : $x = vec(\mathbf{X})$.

My code that returns $\mathbf{A}x$ can be expressed as follows:

$\mathbf{A}x = \mathbf{R} \, \mathbf{\mathcal{F}}^{-1} (\mathbf{D} \circ \mathbf{S} \circ (\mathcal{F}\mathbf{X}))$

where $\circ$ is the Hadamard product, $\mathbf{R}, \mathbf{S}$ and $\mathbf{D}$ are explicit matrices that I have, and $\mathcal{F}$ is the Fourier transform.

Now to the question:

> How can I obtain $\mathbf{A}$ from the above equation in order to define an expression for $\mathbf{A}^*$?

My initial attempt was as follows:

$x^* \mathbf{A}^* = (\mathbf{D}^* \circ \mathbf{S}^* \circ (\mathbf{X}^* \mathcal{F}^{-1})) \; \mathcal{F} \; \mathbf{R}^*$

but I'm clueless as to how to isolate $\mathbf{A}^*$ such that it can be passed to the SPGL solver to perform the implicit matrix multiplication $\mathbf{A}^*r$. Note that I can not afford to store $\mathcal{F}$ as an explicit matrix.

Thank you for your help. Any ideas or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I could not parse your definition of the operator A.  If D and S are matrices, do you build the Hadamard product with the matrix of the Fourier transform?

Comment: Hi Dirk... Yes, I take the Fourier transform of x, then perform a Hadamard product of that with D and S

Comment: Err... So x is a matrix?

Comment: well, actually $x$ is a vectorization of an original multidimensional matrix: $x = vec(\hat{x})$  ... so $x$ is a vector not a matrix; and in my code I do the necessary reshaping (from vector to matirx form) whenever necessary

Comment: Sorry, but this does not make sense. What is the Hadamard product of the matrix S and the vector Fx?

Comment: Sorry if it was confusing. I have now updated the question with a clearer notation.

Comment: Ok, I see now. I think a better fit for this question would be http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/. Anyway: The adjoint is defined by $\langle A^* y,x\rangle = \langle y,Ax\rangle$. You do adjoints one by one from outside to inside.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite get the definition you mentioned $\langle A^* y,x\rangle = \langle y,Ax\rangle $ ... the thing is I don't have $A$, so how can I get its adjoint?